# Jenkins - Display names of failed tests TestNG

Tags: selenium, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, testng, slack

In my Jenkinsfile i'm counting all test results as

```
AbstractTestResultAction testResultAction = currentBuild.rawBuild.getAction(AbstractTestResultAction.class)
    if (testResultAction != null) {
        def total = testResultAction.totalCount
        def failed = testResultAction.failCount
        def skipped = testResultAction.skipCount
        def passed = total - failed - skipped
```

But I also want to display all names of failed tests for slack message.
So far, i've tried to generate it with `def failedTests = testResultAction.getResult().getFailedTests()` but it returns not specific name like `hudson.tasks.junit.CaseResult@37e0fb97`.
Is there anyway to display full name of test? I am using Selenium + TestNG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get description using `.getTitle()` method:

```
def failedTests = testResultAction.getResult().getFailedTests().collect { it.getTitle() }
```

Comment: This is awesome, thank you! I had to approve a lot of these method signatures at `/manage/scriptApproval/` to get it to work.